# Textbook for Partial Differential Equations with a viewpoint towards Geometry

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, textbook-recommendation

I don't know whether I should ask this question here or not but I asked this question on MSE but didn't get any answer so I am posting it here.

Though similar questions have been asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/good-1st-pde-book-for-self-study and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194152/good-reference-texts-for-introduction-to-partial-differential-equation?lq=1 but none of them really answer my query, so I am bounded to ask this.

I am basically interested in Differential and Riemannian Geometry and one of my Professors told me that it will be a good idea if I acquire a sound knowledge of PDE. I know about the basics of PDE (i.e., methods of solving PDE ) but I don't have any firm knowledge of the analysis which goes on in there.

So, my question is that what will be a good textbook to start learning PDE that could help in undrstanding the $\it{analysis}$ portion as well as with applications of PDE in Differential/Riemannian Geometry.

Background : I have studied Measure Theory, Functional Analysis, Complex Analysis and some Fourier Analysis (from Stein & Shakarchi's book on Fourier Analysis). I am currently studying Algebraic Topology, Differential and Riemannian Geometry (from Do Carmo's book).

Thanks!!

Comment: You can try chapters 10 and 11 in my book  http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thanks a lot for the lecture notes ...i will have a look at them

Comment: This is basically the same question as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140399/book-recommendation-pdes-for-geometricians-topologists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aubin, [Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry](http://books.google.ie/books/about/Some_Nonlinear_Problems_in_Riemannian_Ge.html?id=l2nEoSxpHfoC&redir_esc=y)

Struwe, [Variational Methods](http://books.google.ie/books?id=8Ff2M9jBdJAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: thanks for the links ... i'll have a look at these books

Answer (score 2):

Try Jost: *Partial Differential Equations.*